# Retrieve records according to a regex from a SQLite db in QT (C++)

Tags: c++, regex, qt, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve records from a `SQLite` database using `QSqlDatabase` and `QSqlQuery` in `QT/C++`. My query would look like :

```
select * from tableName where columnName REGEXP 'regex'
```

Some sources says to create a function named `REGEXP`, but I couldn't find any clue related to `QT/C++`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/supporting-regular-expressions-in-sqlite/), you need to provide some native C/C++ code that exports regular expression power to SQL. You do that by calling the function [sqlite3_create_function_v2](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html), which is part of the SQL library written in C.

Since [QSqlDatabase](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QSqlDatabase.html) is a generic SQL wrapper designed to support a large number of SQL engines, the provided functions are the lowest common denominator of all of them. Thus you can not access `sqlite3_create_function_v2` from Qt.

If you need to use REGEXP in your Qt application, you need to do use the plain C sqlite library in your entire project. A C++ wrapper around SQLite is advisable but from my own experience [there](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) is nothing that works great, which is why we are developing our own one. Digging into SQLite can be a lot of pain, especially when you start to combine different C++ build systems. So be warned and ask yourself, if you really really really need REGEXP.

Answer (score 3):

As of Qt version 5.10, REGEXP can be used with SQLite without implementing it yourself. However, it is disabled by default. To enable it, set the flag QSQLITE_ENABLE_REGEXP in the connection options.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setConnectOptions("QSQLITE_ENABLE_REGEXP");
```

See [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#setConnectOptions)